# Which of two overloaded templates will be called?

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates

I am still trying to figure out templates. I have read about the specialization rules and don't understand what is happening here.

I have defined the following in templates.h:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename foo>
void f(foo p)
{
  std::cout << "one" << std::endl;
}

template <typename bar>
void f(int p)
{
  std::cout << "two" << std::endl;
}
```

Now if I include this and call it in my main like this

```
  f(1);
  f("x");
```

I get

```
one
one
```

Now the questions is, why is the first more specific than the second for ints? I feel like it should at least be ambiguous and not work at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second overload one has no template dependency on function arguments, so you would have to call it like this:

```
f<std::string>(1);
f<double>(42);
f<SomeType>(1);
```

Whether it makes sense to have the second version is a different matter. You could imagine having a template parameter that *does* have some effect on the internal logic of the function:

```
template <typename SomeType>
int foo(int seed) {
  // instantiate a SomeType and use it to calculate return value
};

int i = foo<Type1>(42);
int j = foo<Type2>(42);
```

On the other hand, your `SomeType` could be a function parameter:

```
template <typename SomeType>
int foo(int seed, const SomeType& s) {
  // use s to calculate return value
};

Type1 t1;
Type2 t2;
int i = foo(42, t1);
int j = foo(42, t2);
```

Answer (score 5):

First off, you don't have specializations, but two separate, unrelated **overloads**.

Secondly, the second overload is trivially non-viable, since you call the function without template arguments, and thus there is no way to deduce the template parameter `bar`. So only the first overload is viable, and gets used.

---

An actual *specialization* would look like this:

```
template <>
void f<int>(int p) { /* ... */ }
```

Better yet, stick with overloads (it's generally better to overload functions than to provide template specializations), but make the second one a non-template:

```
void f(int p) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: I wanted to use this because I have read that it is better to stick with overloads. With "specialization rules" I was referring to the rules that decide which template is used because it is "most specialized". ( http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm )

Answer (score 1):

In the second one `bar` cannot be deduced from function arguments, and must be given explicitly:

```
f<whatever>(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The one, which prints "two" is not recognized as explicit specialization. Try thisL

```
template <>
void f(int p)
{
  std::cout << "two" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: please for sanity's sake, stop posting "Try this"-answers. Rather write "That's because"-answers. "Try this"-answers only indicate that the poster doesn't understand what he has just posted and may or may not work and usually doesn't help at all, especially not in the future.